# Getting child component data without interfering with render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent child that looks like

```
        <SelectedPaginator>
                <DisplayComponent/>
        </SelectedPaginator>
```

It turns out that `<DisplayComponent/>` has information that needs to be retrieved so that `<SelectedPaginator>` can render properly. So I set up a callback that I assign to a property so that `<DisplayComponent/>` can share this information. When the callback is made I save the information passed in state of the 'parent' component (in this case `<SelectedPaginator>`). The problem that I am running into is that when I set the state (using the `useState` hook) I get an exception that I am not able to update a component while another is rendering. How do I successfully setState in the parent without interfering with the rendering of the child? Or how do I find out what is currently being rendered so I can focus on the error? I am currently using `useEffect` to control the timing of the call.